# How to create a new pandas column by splitting an existing one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DF which looks like:

```
Keyword |              ranks              | search_type |   search_volume
kw1     |[{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]|  1          |   500
kw1     |[{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]|  2          |   500
kw2     |[{'rank': 2, 'url': example.com}]|  1          |   1500
kw2     |[{'rank': 2, 'url': example.com}]|  2          |   1500
kw3     |[{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]|  1          |   60
kw3     |[{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]|  2          |   60
```

what I want to is split `ranks` into two columns: `ranks` which contains the rank, and a new column called `url` which contains the url, so the resulting df will look like:

```
Keyword |   ranks    |        url          | search_type |   search_volume
kw1     |[{'rank': 1 | 'url': example.com}]|  1          |   500
kw1     |[{'rank': 1 | 'url': example.com}]|  2          |   500
kw2     |[{'rank': 2 | 'url': example.com}]|  1          |   1500
kw2     |[{'rank': 2 | 'url': example.com}]|  2          |   1500
kw3     |[{'rank': 1 | 'url': example.com}]|  1          |   60
kw3     |[{'rank': 1 | 'url': example.com}]|  2          |   60
```

So far I've tried:

`df.ranks = df.ranks.str.split(',',1).tolist()` which brings back a list of `Nan`s, I've also tried `df['ranks'].str.split(',', expand=True)` which doesn't work. I tried:

`df = pd.DataFrame(df.ranks.str.split(' ',1).tolist(),columns = ['ranks','url'])`

but I get `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 400), indices imply (2, 400)` returned.

EDIT: `df.ranks.dtype` returns `dtype('0')`
`type(df.ranks)` returns `pandas.core.series.Series`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strip` and `split` with expand parameter set to true i.e

```
df[['rank','url']] = df['ranks'].str.strip('{[]}').str.split(',',expand=True).values

  Keyword                              ranks  search_type  search_volume       rank                  url
0  kw1       [{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]            1            500  'rank': 1   'url': example.com
1  kw1       [{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]            2            500  'rank': 1   'url': example.com
2  kw2       [{'rank': 2, 'url': example.com}]            1           1500  'rank': 2   'url': example.com
3  kw2       [{'rank': 2, 'url': example.com}]            2           1500  'rank': 2   'url': example.com
4  kw3       [{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]            1             60  'rank': 1   'url': example.com
5  kw3       [{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]            2             60  'rank': 1   'url': example.com
```

You can also go for converting the string to dict if not i.e

```
df[['rank','url']] =pd.concat(df['ranks'].apply(literal_eval).apply(pd.io.json.json_normalize).tolist()).values

# df[['rank','url']] =pd.concat(df['ranks'].apply(pd.io.json.json_normalize).tolist()).values # If you have lists with dict 

  Keyword                                ranks  search_type  search_volume  rank          url
0  kw1       [{'rank': 1, 'url': "example.com"}]            1            500     1  example.com
1  kw1       [{'rank': 1, 'url': "example.com"}]            2            500     1  example.com
2  kw2       [{'rank': 2, 'url': "example.com"}]            1           1500     2  example.com
3  kw2       [{'rank': 2, 'url': "example.com"}]            2           1500     2  example.com
4  kw3       [{'rank': 1, 'url': "example.com"}]            1             60     1  example.com
5  kw3       [{'rank': 1, 'url': "example.com"}]            2             60     1  example.com
```

Comment: I tried this but I get this error back: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: ain't the `ranks`  string dtype?  perhaps try with `df['ranks'].astype(str).str.....`

Comment: thanks. my full statement is `df[['rank','url']] = df['ranks'].astype(str).str.strip('{[]}').str.split(',',expand=True).values` which returns `KeyError: "['rank' 'url'] not in index"` which I don't understand why it's returning.

Comment: @jceg316 try doing somthing like `df['rank'] = 'nan'` `df['url'] = 'nan'`, sometimes pandas expects column to be already present in the dataframe

Answer (score 2):

I think there are `list`s with `dicts`, so suggest use list comprehension with select first dictionary of list and select by `key`s:

```
df['r'] = [x[0]['rank'] for x in df['ranks']]
df['u'] = [x[0]['url'] for x in df['ranks']]
print (df)
  Keyword                                ranks  search_type  search_volume  r  \
0     kw1  [{'rank': 1, 'url': 'example.com'}]            1            500  1   
1     kw1  [{'rank': 1, 'url': 'example.com'}]            2            500  1   
2     kw2  [{'rank': 2, 'url': 'example.com'}]            1           1500  2   
3     kw2  [{'rank': 2, 'url': 'example.com'}]            2           1500  2   
4     kw3  [{'rank': 1, 'url': 'example.com'}]            1             60  1   
5     kw3  [{'rank': 1, 'url': 'example.com'}]            2             60  1   

             u  
0  example.com  
1  example.com  
2  example.com  
3  example.com  
4  example.com  
5  example.com
```

Or:

```
df['r'] = [{'rank': x[0]['rank']} for x in df['ranks']]
df['u'] = [{'url': x[0]['url']} for x in df['ranks']]
print (df)
  Keyword                                ranks  search_type  search_volume  \
0     kw1  [{'rank': 1, 'url': 'example.com'}]            1            500   
1     kw1  [{'rank': 1, 'url': 'example.com'}]            2            500   
2     kw2  [{'rank': 2, 'url': 'example.com'}]            1           1500   
3     kw2  [{'rank': 2, 'url': 'example.com'}]            2           1500   
4     kw3  [{'rank': 1, 'url': 'example.com'}]            1             60   
5     kw3  [{'rank': 1, 'url': 'example.com'}]            2             60   

             r                       u  
0  {'rank': 1}  {'url': 'example.com'}  
1  {'rank': 1}  {'url': 'example.com'}  
2  {'rank': 2}  {'url': 'example.com'}  
3  {'rank': 2}  {'url': 'example.com'}  
4  {'rank': 1}  {'url': 'example.com'}  
5  {'rank': 1}  {'url': 'example.com'}
```

Comment: for this I'm getting `KeyError: 'url'`

Comment: What is source of data? some `json` ?

Comment: Maybe necesarry first step `df['ranks'] = df['ranks'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` or `df['ranks'] = df['ranks'].astype(str).apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: Yes it's from an API

Comment: @jceg316 - then suggest use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

`df['ranks'].str.split(', ', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'ranks',1:'url'}`)

```
   Keyword                               ranks   search_type   search_volume
0  kw1       [{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]              1            500
1  kw1       [{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]              2            500
2  kw2       [{'rank': 2, 'url': example.com}]              1           1500
3  kw2       [{'rank': 2, 'url': example.com}]              2           1500
4  kw3       [{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]              1             60
5  kw3       [{'rank': 1, 'url': example.com}]              2             60
         ranks                   url
0  [{'rank': 1  'url': example.com}]
1  [{'rank': 1  'url': example.com}]
2  [{'rank': 2  'url': example.com}]
3  [{'rank': 2  'url': example.com}]
4  [{'rank': 1  'url': example.com}]
5  [{'rank': 1  'url': example.com}]
```

Comment: I tried this but it returns a 1x400 df of `NaN` values

Comment: @jceg316 - where you are getting NaN. I didn't understand. I got the output with the same code

Comment: His ranks column is not a string

Comment: @jceg316 - If your column is not a string type please add this line,
df['ranks']=df['ranks'].astype(str)

Comment: @MohamedALANI - Added to the comment :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Please, don't use that strip and split hacks. If you have your input data as string jsons, than just use:

```
import json

df['rank'].map(lambda x: json.loads(x)[0]['rank'])
df['url'].map(lambda x: json.loads(x)[0]['url'])
```